# Tracking history object and assigning value to a list - Query

Tags: field-history

Here Role is a related object to Account . Hence , multiple records will be there . So fetching all the latest values from each record.

In the list , I have collected the last value of the Status field of Role object . Then I would like to iterate through that list and check if any value in `pc` list is not equal to lapsed . if yes , then add to another list . Please help me out in the syntax/code.

Currently , list `pc` is not returning the History records in Debug logs.

```
List<Role__c> pc = [SELECT Status__c , ( SELECT NewValue , createddate 
                                              FROM Histories 
                                              WHERE Field ='Status' 
                                              ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1) 
                       FROM Role__c WHERE Accountid= :AccountList];

List<String> ActiveRole = new List<String>();
        for (Role__c pl : pc) {
            if(pc.Histories.isEmpty())
            {
             if(pl.status__!='Lapsed')
             {
                  ActiveRole.add(pl.status__c);
             }
             else 
             {
             if(pl.Histories[0].NewValue!='Lapsed')
             {


             ActiveRole.add(pl.Histories[0].NewValue);
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: did you checked if role record exist for this account?

Comment: @TusharSharma - It's returning result without the inner query . Whereas inner query is returning result separately.

Comment: so there will be no child record related to this.

Comment: @TusharSharma - No child record to Role__c object

Comment: no child record for this particular record.

Comment: @TusharSharma - The inner query is coming blank. But when queried separately , value is there.

Comment: Because there is no Histories  related to role record you are quering